# How to get not existing records in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following bellow result correct, I need the Record of 
`07/06/2015 0` in between the bellow figure. I did in the Row data bound and some trials in SQL query also. But no clue.

**My Query**

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(nvarchar(15), TransDate, 103) billdate,
    ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(int, Amount)), '0') Amount
FROM HMS_DiagnosisTransactions
WHERE
    TransDate BETWEEN '2015-06-06 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-06-09 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(nvarchar(15), TransDate, 103),
    status,
    CAST(TransDate AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(TransDate AS date)
```

**Result is**

[image: Result]

Comment: Why can't you write down the query instead of posting an image?

Comment: Ok, I will update my Question

Comment: Are you trying to say that if the record of date 07/06/2015 is not available in the database, it must still show in the output with amount 0?

Comment: @ Akash Amin: Ya Correct

Comment: What is the largest date range that you want to run your report for? e.g. 5 days, 50 days?

Comment: @Alex: Sorry to say this,  That is not in my hand. Client will search what Date range he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,'2015-06-06 00:00:00.000') as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < '2015-06-09 00:00:00.000'
)
select CONVERT(nvarchar(15), d.date, 103) billdate,
    ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(int, hd.Amount)), '0') Amount from dates d
left join HMS_DiagnosisTransactions hd on convert(date,d.date) = convert(date,hd.TransDate)         
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(nvarchar(15), d.date, 103),
    hd.status,
    CAST(d.date AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(d.date AS date)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

Comment: Showing from 6 to 9 dates as Amount 0

Comment: Can you Provide Sample data from 6 to 8 day

Comment: `d.date` is `datetime`, while `TransDate` is `nvarchar(15)`. Can they be joined?

Comment: you need to add MAXRECURSION option, else report covering more than 100 days (at default settings) will crash

Comment: +1 for doing exactly what I was doing! You beat me to it because I was trying to type it on a phone. My only suggestion is to add OPTION (MaxRecursion 100) to the end. Increase 100 to a higher number to support more than 100 days in the recursive common table expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to create a master table storing all the bill dates you are going to show.

```
CREATE TABLE MasterDate 
(
    mDate nvarchar(15)
)
GO
```

Add proper entries, for example

```
INSERT INTO MasterDate (mDate) VALUES ('06/06/2015');
INSERT INTO MasterDate (mDate) VALUES ('07/06/2015');
INSERT INTO MasterDate (mDate) VALUES ('08/06/2015');
GO
```

Then join this master table with yours

```
SELECT
    m.mDate AS billdate,
    isnull(t.Amount, 0)
FROM
    MasterDate m 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(15), TransDate, 103) billdate, ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(int, Amount)), '0') Amount
    FROM HMS_DiagnosisTransactions
    WHERE TransDate BETWEEN '2015-06-06 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-06-09 00:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(nvarchar(15), TransDate, 103), status, CAST(TransDate AS date)
    ORDER BY CAST(TransDate AS date)
) t ON m.mDate = t.billdate
```

With this all bill date rows would be shown. If there's no entry in your result, the `Amount` should be null as a result of `LEFT JOIN` and later shown as `0` with the `ISNULL` function. Hope this helps.

Comment: IMO your idea has merit in some circumstances but the example you provide needs polishing.